# Rails devise app to create a REST api for mobile application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, mobile, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm building a REST api using Rails 4 to be used in a mobile application. I'm using devise for Users. 
Api operations will only be accesible by logged in users.

I've been looking how to perform this. 
1. The first solution I see is using token_authentication but it has been disabled by devise.
2. If I try to log-in using normal controllers I get a "Can't verify CSRF token authenticity"

How should I proceed?

Comment: If you're using HTTP API calls, you don't need to include CSRF authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token` to your API controller.
But true way for this case it's https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper